# Exibir dados de duas tabelas na grid com YII framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Olá,

Estou iniciando como desenvolver web e estou com um problema no trabalho com o YII framework 1.

Tenho na aplicação uma grid que exibe: **nome do produto, segmento, preço**. Todos esses dados vem do banco em duas tabelas **cliente** e **produtos**. 
O problema é que a grid lista todos esses itens de todos os clientes cadastrados. Eu tenho que fazer com que a grid exiba somente os produtos, segmento, preço do cliente logado, e não de todos.

```
Tabela_cliente (cod_cliente(PK), nome_cliente,end_cliente)
Tabela_produto(cod_produto(PK),segmento, preço)
```

Não sei se tem que criar uma tabela `produto_cliente`, onde fazer essa verificação para entrar os dados na grid.

Não consigo mostrar nada de código pois a empresa não permite por motivos de contrato.

Alguém da um help? Sei que deve ser algo de relacionamento mas onde fazer isso no meu código?

Answer (score 0):

Qual o relacionamento entre produtos e clientes? Pois um relacionamento **muitos para muitos** precisa de uma tabela auxiliar(produto_cliente), porem se for um relacionamento do tipo **um para muitos** você consegue resolver com um chave estrangeira.

Comment: Eu criei a tabela auxiliar e resolvi com INNER Join .